# Converting expression markings to "music character style" in Sibelius

Tags: sibelius

I have a fairly long piece with a fair few dynamic markings, but I've only just realised that you can get the traditional dynamic font ("music character style") by holding down Cmd (I'm on Mac) before typing "mf"/"mp" etc.

Is there a fast way to retrospectively change this rather than deleting and re-entering dozens of dynamic markings? I tried using the Inspector but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: the font is "Opus Text Std" in the Inspector after using Shift + Alt + D to select all expression markings and hairpins.

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin Change Dynamics.    It's very well explained here.

https://www.rpmseattle.com/of_note/enter-and-edit-dynamics-as-music-text-characters-in-sibelius/

You suggested: "Figured it out: the font is "Opus Text Std" in the Inspector after using Shift + Alt + D to select all expression markings and hairpins."

That won't quite do it right.

Comment: What is "that", and why won't it quite work? And how does one fix it once the link goes dead?

Comment: 'That' is the solution mentioned in the OP's reply  - "Figured it out: the font is "Opus Text Std" in the Inspector after using Shift + Alt + D to select all expression markings and hairpins."   In the unlikely event of the link to 'Of Note' dying, revert to my basic answer 'Use the plugin Change Dynamics'.   I'll clarify my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @LaurencePayne Is this best served as a comment to that answer, then?

Comment: No.  Because it's primarily an answer.  Perhaps I should reverse its two halves.

Comment: Can you explain why my solution won't do it right? Looks fine to me.